# Is it formal to fetch data by updating in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
// Sample Code

const [anyState, setAnyState] = useState<number>(0);

const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const rsp = await fetch(...);
    setData(rsp)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
},[anyState]);


return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => setAnyState(prev => prev + 1)}>Update</button> // is it recommended?
    <button onClick={() => fetchData()}>Update</button> // I think it is general way.
  </>
)
```

I just wonder, is it general to fetch data using useEffect in React?
Also, is it recommended?

Comment: There is no other way as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the new [React docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#what-are-good-alternatives-to-data-fetching-in-effects)

> Writing fetch calls inside Effects is a popular way to fetch data, especially in fully client-side apps.

So far my team left the tradional approach of fetching data on useEffects, and we switched to [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/), we gain a lot of benefit, in terms of performance & developer experience as useQuery comes with a lot of instrument to handle the request

Comment: It still uses `useEffect` underneath though

Comment: @Konrad it more than just an `useEffect`, [reference](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/inside-react-query)